# How to export package files in document based application on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

in my app, I want to load certain image user picks, make some modification, after that, save a copy in my own file format. Since I want to keep track of user modification, I decided to export my file as a package(bundle).

So, in my document class, there's a `NSImage` object that holds the image file. In the `fileWrapperOfType:error:` method, I've setup a `NSFileWrapper` object, and put the object in it. Here's the code:

```
NSDictionary *fileWrappers = [self.documentFileWrapper fileWrappers];
if (image != nil) {
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [image bitmapImageRepresentation];
    NSData *imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
    NSFileWrapper *imageFileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc]
                                       initRegularFileWithContents:imageData];
    [imageFileWrapper setPreferredFilename:@"image"];

    [[self documentFileWrapper] addFileWrapper:imageFileWrapper];
}

return self.documentFileWrapper;
```

In my project plist file, I have two document types, first is the type of `public.image` since I need to load images in my app:

[image]

The other one is my own document type. To make the file a package, I've checked the bundle checkbox in xcode:

[image]

If I simply run this now, the code compains that finding extension from type identifier is deprecated, so, I managed to add an entry in `Exported UTIs`:

[image]

At this moment, everything seems working, except that the outputed `folder` with `mdc` extension, is indeed a folder instead of a package, what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the problem, the key here is to change `Conforms To` field to `com.apple.package`.

Comment: I have set "Comforms To" as `com.apple.package`, but it also outputed as a folder, not a package. I don't know why? I'm using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.3.

Comment: After added an image document type like yours, it was working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a package on OS X to be a pkg, it must have a **.pkg** extension. I hope it is as simple as having the wrong extension.

Note: Until recently, .pkg files *were merely directories.* Now, we often see package.pkg packages that are obscured cannot be browsed causually without some tricks like using Pacifist, pkgutil or xar:

pkgutil --extract file.pkg folder/

or

xar -xf file.pkg